# How to connect to API via TCP in reactnative

Tags: reactjs, sockets, react-native, tcp

I am new react native and trying to connect to an URL "someurl.com" which is running on port 8051 via TCP.

I have tried it through web socket but its not working.

In iOS they have implemented it by using streams. Below is the code sample in iOS.

```
CFReadStreamRef  readStream;
CFWriteStreamRef writeStream;
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(
    NULL, 
    (CFStringRef)/*DemoServer_Client, DemoServer_Client_Port*/ /*DemoServer*/ClientServer, 
    Client_Production_Port, 
    &readStream, 
    &writeStream);
```

I have tried it by using react-native-tcp npm but it's giving `undefined object near Socket.connect`. Please see below screenshot.
[sockets connect error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F0RD.png)

Please help me in connecting to this server and getting the response in react-native.

Thanks

Comment: Is there a good way of doing this that you've found?